# Realizing groups as commutator subgroups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

What are the groups $X$ for which there exists a group $G$ such that $G' \cong X$?

My considerations:

---

$\bullet$ If $X$ is perfect we are happy with $G=X$.

$\bullet$ If $X$ is abelian then $G := X \wr C_2$ verifies $G'=\{(x,x^{-1}): x \in X\} \cong X$.

$\bullet$ If $X$ satisfies the following properties:

(1) $X \neq X'$, (2) The conjugation action $X \to \text{Aut}(X)$ is an isomorphism,

then there is no $G$ such that $G' = X$ (consider the composition $G \to \text{Aut}(X) \cong X \to X/X'$, it is surjective so its kernel contains $X$, contradiction). For instance, the symmetric group $S_n$ verifies (1) and (2) if $n \neq 2,6$.

---

I have been looking for this problem on the web but I didn't find anything.
Do you have any reference and/or suggestion on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A complete answer seems not to be known.  Let me give you the following two nearly-contemporaneous references from the mid-70s:

Robert Guralnick, *On groups with decomposable commutator subgroups*

Michael Miller, *Existence of Finite Groups with Classical Commutator Subgroup*

Both Guralnick and Miller call groups which are commutator subgroups $C$-groups (though I don't know who, if either, originated the term) and give partial answers to your general question.  For example, Theorem 4 from Miller gives the following:

> Let $G$ be a subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}_n(K)$ containing $\operatorname{SL}_n(K)$ for $K$ a finite field of characteristic not equal to 2.  Then $G$ is the commutator subgroup of some group unless it is of odd index and $n$ is even.

The groupprops-wiki calls such groups commutator-realizable, and give a basic result on such groups, but mention that this terminology is not standard (though is probably safer than the overloaded term $C$-group.)

Edit:  Some googling around led to the following slick argument of Schoof (from his *Semistable abelian varieties with good reduction outside 15*), which is closely related to your observation in bullet (3), and also serves to eliminate the symmetric groups.  I'll quote verbatim except for change of variable names:

> Let $G$ be a group and let $G'$ be its commutator subgroup. Conjugation gives rise to
> a homomorphism $G \to \operatorname{Aut}(G')$. On the one hand it maps $G'$ to the commutator subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut}(G')$. On the other hand the image of $G'$ is the group $\operatorname{Inn}(G')$ of inner automorphisms of $G'$. Therefore, if a group $X$ is the commutator subgroup of some group, we must have $\operatorname{Inn}(X)\subset \operatorname{Aut}(X)'$.

Answer (score 7):

Let me quote some well-known results and perhaps related problems which may be illuminating!

Let $G$ be a non-abelian finite $p$-group having cyclic center. Then, there is no finite $p$-group $H$ such that $G$ is isomorphic to a normal subgroup of the derived subgroup $[H,H]$ of $H$. In particular, $G$ cannot be isomorphic to the derived subgoup of some $p$-group $H$. The latter is a famous result due to Burnside. The former is a slight generalization of  problem. See  H. Heineken, On normal embedding of subgroups. 
Geom. Dedicata 83, No.1-3, 211-216 (2000).

Related problem: Let $V$ be a non-empty set of words in the free group on the countable set
$\{x_1,x_2,\dots\}$. We call a group $G$ is {\bf integrable with respect to $V$}, whenever there is a group $H$ such that $G\cong V(H)$, where $V(H)$ is the verbal subgroup of $H$ generated by $V$, i.e., $$V(H)=\langle v(h_1,\dots,h_n) | v\in V, h_i \in H \rangle,$$
(the subgroup of $H$ generated by the values of words of $V$ on the elements of $H$)
For example, if one takes $V=\{[x_1,x_2]=x_1^{-1}x_2^{-1}x_1 x_2\}$, then $V(H)$ is the derived subgroup of $H$ for any group $H$ and the problem is the same as it proposed.
One may write (maybe for some propaganda) 
$$\int G \; dV=H \Longleftrightarrow G=V(H).$$ 
In the case, $V=\{ [x_1,x_2]\}$, $$\int G=H  \Longleftrightarrow G=H'$$ and so
$$\int G=H \Longleftrightarrow \int G=H \times A$$ for any abelian group $A$. (This may remind the constant term in the integral of a function!)
I have used the latter notation which has no benefit but only perhaps inspiring  in 
[A. Abdollahi, Integral of a group, 29th Iranian International Conference on Mathematics, Amirkabir University of Technology (Tehran Polytechnic), Iran, March 28-31, 1998.]

I would like to say that the problem `given a group $G$, find groups $H$ such that $G=[H,H]$" have been studied in a more general contex which may be found with key words`normal embedding of subgroups" and the above-mentioned paper of Heineken is a good start.

Also it may be worth-mentioning that by a result of Allenby 
R.B.J.T. Allenby, Normal subgroups contained in Frattini subgroups are Frattini subgroups, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc,  Vol. 78, No. 3,  1980, 318-

if $N$ is a normal subgroup of a finite group $G$ which is contained in the Frattini subgroup of $G$, then $N=\Phi(U)$ for some finite group $U$.

Of course, for the class of finite $p$-groups the Frattini subgroup is the verbal subgroup
generated by the words $x_1^p, [x_1,x_2]$.