# Given any group G, how can we construct another group H such that G is isomorphic to the commutator subgroup H' of H?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

First of all, it's not true that any group can be realized as the commutator subgroup of some group. So, if we assume that there is atleast one group H with H' isomorphic to G, how to construct *all* such groups H?

To start with, we may assume that G is finite. Can we classify all (finite) groups with commutator subgroup isomorphic to G?

Comment: What is your motivation for the question.. just out of curiosity I am asking...

Comment: I suppose you know that any finite Abelian group $G$ is isomorphic to $H^{\prime},$ where $H = G \wr \left( \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \right).$ Probably OK for infinite Abelian groups too.

Comment: @Praphulla  Random thought!

Comment: @Geoff  Thanks for this information. Didn't know this result! Can you please provide some reference where I can find the proof?

Comment: @Dey you can rather prove it as an exercise: what is the derived subgroup of $G\wr C_2=(G\times G)\rtimes C_2$ (action by flip), for $G$ abelian?

Comment: Abstract concept can come from random thought (which still needs proof but not in the beginning)... if you are asking for all groups having some property you better have one example of a group where you have that property.. My comment is also random thought :D

Comment: I think any semidirect product $H.A$ with $A$ an Abelian group of automorphisms of $H$ acting trivially on $H/H^{\prime}$ will also have derived group  $H^{\prime}.$

Comment: How is the second question different from asking for the commutator subgroup of every finite group? I think this is way too broad.

Comment: @verret I agree it's broad but disagree that it's the same as asking the commutator subgroup of every finite group... for instance say for the group $G=C_2$, the question makes sense and does not reduce in such a tautological way. The answer then starts with $H=P\times A$ where $A$ is abelian of odd order and $P$ is a 2-group with derived subgroup $C_2$. Then the description of such 2-groups is a reasonable question. The OP should maybe specify what (s)he did so far.

Comment: See the following post                                                          https://mathoverflow.net/questions/85540/realizing-groups-as-commutator-subgroups/86358#86358